# Flutter bloc how to call event the right way?

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, flutter-bloc

I have a quite complex app structure and im wondering how to handle calling my events the right way. Imagine my widget tree. On top of everything I have the following file `AppWrapper` with this

**1. level file AppWrapper**

```
...
return BlocProvider(
        create: (context) => EventsBloc(
              RepositoryProvider.of<EventRepository>(context),
              RepositoryProvider.of<SocketRepository>(context),
                )..add(LoadEventsEvent()), 
...
child: RootScreen()
    ...
```

It calls `LoadEventsEvent()` perfectly fine. Now in my `RootScreen()` im trying to load a the event again.

**2. level file RootScreen**

```
...
  BlocBuilder<DifferentBloc, DifferentBlocState>(
                    builder: (context, state) {
                  if (state.navbarItem == FMNavigation.home) {
                   
                    // How to load LoadEventsEvent() here the right way??
                      return BlocProvider(
                   create: (context) => EventsBloc(
                     RepositoryProvider.of<EventRepository>(context),
                     RepositoryProvider.of<SocketRepository>(context),
                  )..add(LoadEventsEvent()),
                   child: HomeScreen(),
               
 
                  } else if (state.navbarItem == FMNavigation.chat) {
...
```

Now the above code works fine, its loading `LoadEventsEvent()` like im expecting, but im using `BlocProvider` for `EventsBloc` two times now. From the [docs](https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_bloc/latest/flutter_bloc/BlocProvider-class.html) it says:

> Takes a Create function that is responsible for creating the Bloc or
> Cubit and a child which will have access to the instance via
> BlocProvider.of(context). It is used as a dependency injection (DI)
> widget so that a single instance of a Bloc or Cubit can be provided to
> multiple widgets within a subtree.

It seems like it's not meant to be used multiple times for the same bloc even if it works in my special case. No my second idea was to refactor this code to:

```
...
BlocBuilder<NavigationCubit, NavigationState>(
                    builder: (context, state) {
                  if (state.navbarItem == FMNavigation.home) {
                    context.read<EventsBloc>().add(LoadEventsEvent());
                    return HomeScreen();
                  } else if (state.navbarItem == FMNavigation.chat) {
...
```

But reading about `context.read()` the docs say:

> It will not make widget rebuild when the value changes and cannot be
> called inside [StatelessWidget.build]/[State.build]. On the other
> hand, it can be freely called outside of these methods.
>
> If that is incompatible with your criteria, consider using
> Provider.of(context, listen: false). It does the same thing, but
> without these added restrictions (but unsafe).
>
> DON'T call [read] inside build if the value is used only for events:

Well how can I get this work?

EDIT:

Is this also good to go?

```
child: BlocListener<BlocA, BlocAState>(
      listener: (context, state) {
        // TODO: implement listener
        if (state is LiveeventFinishedState) {
          print('LiveeventFinishedState');
          BlocProvider.of<BlocB>(context).add(LoadJoinableEvent());
          BlocProvider.of<BlocC>(context).add(LoadEventsEvent());
        }
      },
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you don't need to create a new bloc as your `RootScreen` seems to be a a child node of `AppWrapper` in the widget tree, `Provider` will provide data (in this case EventsBloc) to all of its children.

You can access the bloc data by using `context.read()` and add a new event as below:

```
  BlocBuilder<DifferentBloc, DifferentBlocState>(
                builder: (context, state) {
              if (state.navbarItem == FMNavigation.home) {
              
              // you can access the bloc just fine
              context.read<EventsBloc>().add(LoadEventsEvent());
              return HomeScreen(),
           

              } else if (state.navbarItem == FMNavigation.chat) {
```

Comment: thanks for your response. Check my edit, is it also allowed to call different events from another bloc in my listener like in my question?

Comment: ```context.read()``` does not make the widget to rebuild, but your ```BlocBuilder``` or ```BlocListener``` will rebuild/run when the bloc's state change. It is fine to call another bloc from any listener, just make sure you have provide the Bloc in the parent node of the widget tree. What you shouldn't do is to define a bloc inside another bloc class. [More on communication between blocs here](https://bloclibrary.dev/#/architecture?id=bloc-to-bloc-communication)